# How to obtain counts of each of the elements of the list?

Tags: java

Given a sorted list of something (a,a,b,c,c)

What would be the most efficient way to recognize that `a` exists in the list 2 times, `b` once and `c` 2 times?

Aside from obvious making a map of counts. Can we do better then this?

```
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(key, 1);
            }
```

Ultimately the goal is to iterate of the list and know at any given point how many times a key was seen before. Putting things in a map, seems like a step we don't really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method, at each iteration, makes

- one lookup for containsKey
- one lookup for get
- one unboxing from Integer to int
- one boxing from int to Integer
- one put

You could simply compare the current element to the previous one, increment a count if it's equal, and put the count if not (and reset the counter to 1).

But even if you keep your algorithm, using get and compare the result to null would at least avoid an unnecessary lookup.

Comment: I ended up manually writing all the steps as you suggested. Got best performance numbers

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) implementation in [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) - probably a [`HashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html). That avoids having to do a `put`/`get` on each iteration - if the item already exists when you add it, it just increments the count. It's a bit like using a `HashMap<Foo, AtomicInteger>`.

See the [Guava User's Guide entry on `Multiset`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) for more details.

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example?

Comment: @Jam: Did you read the documentation? It's pretty straightforward... Have a go, and if you get stuck, ask for help on a specific piece.

Comment: In my testing, Multiset is about 100 times slower then it's Map equivalent. I suppose this depends on the list size, but generally speaking, is this expected?

Comment: @Jam: No, that sounds distinctly unusual. I'd generally suspect the benchmarking, as it's pretty hard to do well... if you can edit your post with a test case, that would be helpful. (Or perhaps ask that as a separate, Guava-specific question.)

Comment: I will do some more testing and if I see no mistake, i will make a new post. Thank you